# Statistical comparison of grand/pooled means (nested, mixed-model, t tests)

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, mean, software, weighted-mean

My problem: I am comparing the means of means of means in my data set.

However, my stats software (GraphPad Prism) doesn't know that these said individual values (the means of means of means) are composed of multiple pooled values.

Due to this, I believe that the stats software is not lending more weight to the observed differences in my means of means of means.

For example:

- Take 2 groups of values e.g. 2, 5, 4 and 3; and 6, 7, 7 and 9
- If you treated these as 'normal' values (i.e. not means), the stats software would likely return a t-test as not statistically significant in a comparison of the two groups
- However if the stats software 'knew' or 'treated' these and pooled means, it would return a greater statistical difference between the two groups. I would think this would occur because it would attribute a greater weighting to the individual values in both groups

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, then please consider 
[upvoting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) 
and/or 
[accepting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) 
it.

Comment: The premise of your example is wrong. I compared the two sets of data in your example using the ordinary two-sample t-test or the Welch variation using GraphPad Prism and the p-value in both cases was 0.006.

Comment: Note that GraphPad Prism can handle exactly the situation you mention under the name "nested t-test" (a special case of a mixed model). https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/latest/statistics/stat_how-to-nested-t-test.htm

Answer (score 1):

I infer that your question is what can be done about this. You need to take advantage, carefully, of the numbers of relevant observations going into each "mean of means" and of the experimental design structure.

You example data actually are significantly different. I use R instead of GraphPad.

```
t.test(c(2,5,4,3),c(6,7,7,9))
#   Welch Two Sample t-test
# 
# data:  c(2, 5, 4, 3) and c(6, 7, 7, 9)
# t = -4.1603, df = 5.9961, p-value = 0.005951
```

For illustration in a harder case, start with "ideal" values each 2 units lower for the second set. Say that the two sets of values represent two treatments evaluated in 4 separate experiments. Each experiment involved 4 animals for each treatment. That's 32 animals total. Say that experiments are expected to have systematic differences from each other, something captured here by putting both sets of "ideal" values into increasing order.

```
setA <- c(2,3,4,5) ## ideal mean values per experiment, treatment A
setB <- c(4,5,5,7) ## ideal mean values per experiment, treatment B
```

Now there is no "significant" difference between the "means of means" with an unpaired t-test under the usual p < 0.05 criterion.

```
t.test(setA,setB)
#   Welch Two Sample t-test
# 
# data:  setA and setB
# t = -1.9415, df = 5.9961, p-value = 0.1003
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
     3.50      5.25
```

Use these "ideal" values as a guide, but add some randomness. First simulate mean values for each of the 32 individual animals with random variation--normal distributions, standard deviation (SD) of 2--around the above "ideal" mean values.

```
set.seed(101)
indivA <- rnorm(16,mean=rep(setA,each=4),sd=2)
indivB <- rnorm(16,mean=rep(setB,each=4),sd=2)
```

Then simulate 3 technical replicates for each animal around those animal-mean values, with an SD of 3.

```
techA <- rnorm(48,mean=rep(indivA,each=3),sd=3)
techB <- rnorm(48,mean=rep(indivB,each=3),sd=3)
```

Collect these final "measurements" into a dataframe, with `val` the measurement values, `id` representing animals, `experiment` the 4 experiments, and `treatment` of A or B. Use `factor()` to have the numeric labels interpreted correctly as identifiers rather than numbers.

```
df1 <- data.frame(val=c(techA,techB),id=factor(rep(1:32,each=3)),experiment=factor(c(rep(1:4,each=12),rep(1:4,each=12))),treatment=factor(rep(c("A","B"),each=48)))
```

Verify that the simple means of means of means aren't "significantly" different after this added randomness. First get the overall means (each a mean of 3 observations on each of 4 animals) for each experiment/treatment combination.

```
byExpTx <- aggregate(val~experiment+treatment,data=df1,FUN=mean)
byExpTx
#     experiment treatment      val
#   1          1         A 1.314736
#   2          2         A 2.705538
#   3          3         A 4.240616
#   4          4         A 4.847567
#   5          1         B 3.563284
#   6          2         B 4.905319
#   7          3         B 4.957705
#   8          4         B 6.458030
```

An unpaired t-test on those mean values, comparing the 4 experiments under treatment A against the 4 under treatment B, isn't "significant."

```
t.test(byExpTx[1:4,"val"],byExpTx[5:8,"val"])
#   Welch Two Sample t-test
# 
# data:  byExpTx[1:4, "val"] and byExpTx[5:8, "val"]
# t = -1.7533, df = 5.6455, p-value = 0.1332
#
# sample estimates:
# mean of x mean of y 
#  3.277114  4.971085
```

If, however, you take advantage of the structure of the experiments, pairing of treatments within experiments, you see a "significant" difference.

```
t.test(byExpTx[1:4,"val"],byExpTx[5:8,"val"],paired=TRUE)
# 
#   Paired t-test
# 
# data:  byExpTx[1:4, "val"] and byExpTx[5:8, "val"]
# t = -4.7523, df = 3, p-value = 0.01768
```

You can also do better than comparing the means of means of means if you use the information about the number of cases underlying the observations. You might use the average of technical replicates to represent each animal:*

```
byExpTxId <- aggregate(val~experiment+treatment+id,data=df1,FUN=mean)
```

Then even without considering the pairing within experiments:

```
lm1 <- lm(val~treatment,data=byExpTxId)
summary(lm1)
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)   3.2771     0.5546   5.909  1.8e-06
# treatmentB    1.6940     0.7843   2.160   0.0389  
# Residual standard error: 2.218 on 30 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.1346,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.1057 
# F-statistic: 4.665 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 0.0389
```

The "30 degrees of freedom" represent the 32 animals that the calculations now incorporate, less the 2 estimated coefficients. Add in the pairing within experiments to see how that also matters:

```
lm2 <- lm(val~treatment+experiment,data=byExpTxId)
summary(lm2) ## reports of residuals and coefficient values not shown
# Residual standard error: 1.959 on 27 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.3927,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.3027 
# F-statistic: 4.365 on 4 and 27 DF,  p-value: 0.007506

anova(lm2)
# Analysis of Variance Table
# 
# Response: val
#            Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
# treatment   1  22.956 22.9563  5.9832 0.02124
# experiment  3  44.029 14.6765  3.8252 0.02098
# Residuals  27 103.593  3.8368
```

More generally, you might use a mixed model with animals (`id`) (or even `experiment`) treated as random effects, but in this case with a balanced design and underlying normal distributions it doesn't make any difference.

---

*You have to be careful to distinguish the technical replicates within animals from the biological replicates among animals. To evaluate the treatments you need to compare the treatment differences against the differences among animals, not against the differences of technical replicates within animals. Taking the mean of technical replicates is one way to avoid that problem. A mixed model using all of the measurements and treating animals as random effects is another, better particularly if you have different numbers of replicates for each animal. In GraphPad that's what's done in "nested" t-tests and ANOVA.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, then please consider 
[upvoting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) 
and/or 
[accepting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) 
it.